# Does $ x^\dagger M x = \alpha \; x^\dagger x,$ imply $M x = \alpha x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

With $x$ a complex vector, $M$ a complex matrix, and $\alpha$ a scalar, is it correct to say that if
$$ x^\dagger M x = \alpha \; x^\dagger x,$$
then
$$ M x = \alpha x,$$
and therefore $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ ($\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose). If yes, why is it correct and under what conditions? It seems trivial and at the same time with three vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$, if $a.b=a.c$ it doesn't imply $b=c$. (This is not a homework, I am just rusty with my linear algebra and I don't know how to look for the answer).

Answer (score 5):

I assume that $M$ is a square matrix. Suppose that $x$ is not a right eigen-vector of $M$ (and non zero), set $\alpha=\frac{x^\dagger M x}{x^\dagger x}$ to obtain a counter example.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand that, why is that a counter example? (I am also interested in the non square case.)

Comment: If $M$ is not square, then $Mx=\alpha x$ doesn't make sense. This gives you an example of vector $x$ and $\alpha$ such that $Mx\neq\alpha x$ and $x^\dagger M x = \alpha x^\dagger x$, therefore a counter example. Note that some matrix are such that all vectors are eigen-vectors (like the identity), for any other matrix you get a counter example.

Comment: Setting this value for $\alpha$ just leads to 1=1, no? Can you give more details for why this is a counter example? (I get $M$ must be square, indeed.)

Comment: If you develop : $\alpha x^\dagger x=\frac{x^\dagger M x}{x^\dagger x} x^\dagger x = x^\dagger M x$. Not sure what you mean by $1=1$.